# bonobo git server on windows 2012 r2

Tags: bonobo

i try to get bonobo git server running on my Windows server 2012 R2. IIS 8.5
But i am not successfull.

Symptoms:
When browsing to http://localhost/bonobo.git.server/
i get error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

When allowing show folder content, 
i see folder content but no login mask.

All prerequisites fullfiled. So .NET 4.5 installed, ASP. NET.
The bonbo dir has all required privileges.

In my IIS, it looks a bit differently from what i see in the install tutorial.
Have only bonobo.git.server below default website.

The application pool contains .NET v4.5,.NET v4.5 classic, DefaultAppPool

For me it looks like the webserver does not know how to start the webfrontend.

Can anyone help or is there another free Git server for windows which i should use ?

Thank you

Comment: use this link: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=S3Dm2Z-hc1o`. I install successfully.